# Overwrite file on drive using GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have a file named `backup.abc` on my appDataFolder but I want to overwrite everytime a new version of the backup gets generated by my app.

```swift
let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate.query(
  withObject: GTLRDrive_File(),
  fileId: "---fileId_from_backup.abc---",
  uploadParameters: GTLRUploadParameters(
    data: data,
    mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  )
)

service.executeQuery(query) { _, result, error in
  guard let error == nil else { fatalError() }

  if let file = result as? GTLRDrive_File {
     // file.identifier == the same
  }

 // Seems to work fine since no error 
 // gets passed on the completionBlock 
 // but the content doesn't get overwritten.
}
```

I'm currently overcoming this by uploading a different file, deleting the old one, renaming the new one but for sure that's not the way to go. Documentation for this project seems pretty hard to find, it has been pretty much trial and error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the bug wasn't on this code. By the way, the code above is valid for whoever is looking to find a way to call update using Google Drive API in Swift.